# How do I build the "Standard Kraken 2 Database"?

Tags: ngs, linux, metagenome

I am at this point in the GitHub tutorial: https://github.com/DerrickWood/kraken2/blob/master/docs/MANUAL.markdown#standard-kraken-2-database

It says to create the standard Kraken database, I use the following command:

```
kraken2-build --standard --db $DBNAME
```

It then says to change `$DBNAME` with the preferred database name/location. Is this something that I need to download on my own? Where can I find it, and how do I do it?

To provide context, I want to use Kraken2 to identify whether or not there is the presence of MCPyV in a tumor sample.

Comment: If you just want the viral database, read the 'custom databases' section (https://github.com/DerrickWood/kraken2/blob/master/docs/MANUAL.markdown#custom-databases)

Answer (score 2):

\$DBNAME is a folder location on your computer; you specify it yourself, for example:

```
kraken2-build --standard --db /media/ip80/externalDrive/kraken_indexes/betterThanGenbank
```